# how can i set a limit to increment and decrement of value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to to make a quantity increase and decrease using jquery, it's working properly but if once value is 1 then how can i avoid decrements operation. i tried using if else s=conditions but it's not sorted out please teach me...

```js
jQuery('#inc').click(function() {
     jQuery('.output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
 });
jQuery('#dec').click(function() {
    jQuery('.output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1" id="dech">
        <p id="dec">-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <center><b><span class='output' value='1'>1</span> Adult</b></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" id="inch">
        <p id="inc">+</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Math.abs({ return val*1+1 });` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the value is already 1 (or below, just in case) while you decrease. In that case return simply `1`, otherwise go for the decreased value. Note that multiplication `* 1` is used as a means of parsing String to Number in your solution.

```js
jQuery('#inc').click(function() {
     jQuery('.output').html(function(i, val) { return val * 1 + 1 });
 });
jQuery('#dec').click(function() {
    jQuery('.output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1 <= 1 ? 1 : val * 1 - 1 });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1" id="dech">
        <p id="dec">-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <center><b><span class='output' value='1'>1</span> Adult</b></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" id="inch">
        <p id="inc">+</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly i got logic also now thank you very much Freeman Lambda

Comment: Dear Freeman how can i store  <span class='output' value='1'>1</span> This value in jquery variable

Comment: `var spanContent = $('.output').get(0).outerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Change increment/decrement functions like this. You were using a value attribute on span but not incrementing/decrementing its value. Although its not neccesary but I felt that it should updated too.

```
$('#inc').click(function() {
    $('.output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
    $('.output').attr("value",$('.output').html().trim())
});
$('#dec').click(function() {
   if ($(".output").text().trim() === "1") return;
    $('.output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
    $('.output').attr("value",$('.output').html().trim())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1" id="dech">
                        <p id="dec">-</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <center><b><span class='output' value='1'>1</span> Adult</b></center> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1" id="inch">
                        <p id="inc">+</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
<script>
$('#inc').click(function() {
    $('.output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
    $('.output').attr("value",$('.output').html().trim())
});
$('#dec').click(function() {
   if ($(".output").text().trim() === "1") return;
    $('.output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
    $('.output').attr("value",$('.output').html().trim())
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you dec function ensure the value is greater than 1. Working Code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#inc').click(function() {
      $('.output').html(function(i, val) { 
       return val*1+1 
      });
   });
   $('#dec').click(function() {
        $('.output').html(function(i, val) {
         if(val>1)
         return val*1-1 
        });
   }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-1" id="dech">
      <p id="dec">-</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <center><b><span class='output' value='1'>1</span> Adult</b></center> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-1" id="inch">
      <p id="inc">+</p>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear Sudhir Ojha how can i store <span class='output' value='1'>1</span> This value in jquery variable

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the multiplication, but just add an if statment.

```
$('#dec').click(function() {
    $('.output').html(function(i, val) { 
       if(val > 1)
         return val - 1;
    });
});
```

As a ternary:

```
$('#dec').click(function() {
    $('.output').html(function(i, val) { 
         return (val > 1) ? val - 1 : val; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for :D cheers

```js
jQuery('#inc').click(function() {
     jQuery('.output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
 });
jQuery('#dec').click(function() {
    jQuery('.output').html(function(i, val) { let _val; _val = val*1-1 ? val*1-1 : 1; return _val });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1" id="dech">
        <p id="dec">-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <center><b><span class='output' value='1'>1</span> Adult</b></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" id="inch">
        <p id="inc">+</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Akhil your solution is also right thank you very much. how can i store <span class='output' value='1'>1</span> This value in jquery variable

Comment: declare a variable, eg. var currentValue=0; on each click function, store val*1+1 to currentValue and return currentValue

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator like this:

```
$('#inc').click(function () {
  $('.output').html(function (i, val) {
    return val * 1 + 1;
  });
});
$('#dec').click(function () {
  $('.output').html(function (i, val) {
    return val > 1 ? val * 1 - 1 : val;
  });
});
```